# makefile: how to specify header files

Tags: c++, makefile, header-files

I'm trying to write a makefile for all of my cpp prjects. After searching from the internet, I make a makefile as below:

```
g++11=g++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++

CPPFILES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJFILES=$(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o)


res.out: $(OBJFILES)
    $(g++11) -lncurses -o $@ $^ -g

#obj/%.o: %.cpp
%.o: %.cpp
    $(g++11) -c -o $@ $< -g


clean:
    rm *.o *.out
```

I tried to use this file to compile my cpp projects and it worked well.

However, when I make some change in the header files, it doesn't work anymore because this makefile can't detect the modification in header files.

Is there any easy way to specify header files in the makefile?
Ofc I don't want to specify them one by one.

Comment: Look up "make auto dependency generation"

Comment: You could add the header files as a dependency for the `".o"` rule.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews - apart from forcing the OP to "specify them one by one" which he doesn't want to do, that also forces a complete rebuild whenever any header file changes - including compilation units that don't depend on the changed header.    Auto dependency generation uses the compiler (actually preprocessor) to generate a dependency list based on `#include`s in source files, so changing a header only causes recompiling objects that depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should understand the concept of *make*.

Make is not only for compiling C++, it's a universal tool where a product (file) is built from other files. When you issue the *make*, it checks whether the top product should be rebuilt, based on the file change dates of dependencies. If rebuild is needed, first checks all the dependencies whether they should be rebuild... and so on. These bricks are called rules.

This is a *rule*:

```
target: dependency1 dependency2 ...
  command1 to produce targets
  command2
```

In case of a CPP project:

```
myapp: myapp.cpp myapp.hpp
  g++ myapp.cpp -o myapp
```

More info: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gkesden/412-18/fall01/projects/proj1/make/makeintro.html